# Automatically connect to shared device when detected

Tags: macos, network, finder, sharing

Here is my need : I want my media center to be mounted in the `/Volumes` of my Macbook as soon as I turn it on.
So, I need to automate the *Connect as* action.

[image]

*Users & groups > Login items* only resolve one part of the equation : mounting the macmini on laptop startup.

How to silently establish connection if I boot up macmini while laptop is already running ?

**Update:**
http://www.kristijan.org/2010/11/automount-afp-shares-in-osx/ explain how to mount a volume using `automount` command.
Still, **is there an event *"Share just appeared on network"* emitted somehow by the system that I could plug into to trigger when to execute the `automount` command ?**

Comment: Are you familiar with Apple Script?

Comment: I would accept solutions based on apple script :)

Answer (score 1):

You should definately check out google first.

I'm guiding you in the right direction:
[This is a start click here.](http://definitebounds.blogspot.nl/2012/03/applescript-for-mapping-network-drives.html)

Comment: Meh :/ That does not correspond to my problem : no SMB share & Active directory involved here.